# Closure library dom node from html text

Tags: google-closure-library

I have an html text like:

`'<div class="a"><span>1</span><div>2</div></div>'`

Is there a function in closure library to get such a string as input and return a DOM tree to insert in a document?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Closure Library provides the function [**`goog.dom.safeHtmlToNode(html)`**](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/fab924fd90b343996a7a2dbd0ebc1394e63e38a9/closure/goog/dom/dom.js#L907) to create a document fragment (`Node`) from a `goog.html.SafeHtml` object, which can be created using `goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer` as shown below.

## Example

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Closure Library Dom Test</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/closure-library/master/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
  <script>
    goog.require('goog.dom');
    goog.require('goog.html.SafeHtml');
    goog.require('goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer');
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Closure Library Dom Test</h1>

<div id="main">
</div>

<script>
  var sanitizer = new goog.html.sanitizer.HtmlSanitizer.Builder().build();
  var fragment = goog.dom.safeHtmlToNode(
      sanitizer.sanitize('<div class="a"><span>1</span><div>2</div></div>'));

  goog.dom.append(/** @type {!Node} */(document.querySelector('#main')),
      /** @type {!Node} */(fragment));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `goog.dom.htmlToDocumentFragment(htmlString)` is deleted now. Are there any new way for this?

Comment: @red_led Example updated to use `goog.dom.safeHtmlToNode(html)` in place of the deleted `goog.dom.htmlToDocumentFragment`.