# Google Closure alternative to jQuery creating a dom element on the fly

Tags: jquery, google-closure, google-closure-templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closure library dom node from html text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318667/closure-library-dom-node-from-html-text)

in jQuery you can create a dom element like this

```
var domElement = $("<div><p>more tags and html</p></div>");
```

**How do you do the same in Google Closure?**

I don't want to have to include the whole jQuery library for something that seems to minimal.

Comment: See **[Closure library dom node from html text](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12318667/1164465)**

Comment: Exactly the function I was trying to find. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [document](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_dom_dom.js.html)

```
goog.dom.createElement(name); //creates a new element
goog.dom.createDom(tagName, opt_attributes, var_args) //Returns a dom node with a set of attributes.
```

Try(untested code):

```
 var p = goog.dom.createElement('p');
 p.innerHTML = "abc";
 var div =  goog.dom.createDom('div', null, p);
```

I know its not as elegant and clean as jquery :)

Comment: Looking for something where it can be any string of html, rather than a tag name. Probably should of been a bit more specific. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: This does give me a good starting point on implementing a 'collection of elements create function' myself, was hoping something already existed in the closure framework though.